# BroadcastReceiver não esta funcionando

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

Meu BroadcastReceiver não esta funcionando, eu não sei o que tem de errado, no meu Manifest tem isso

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<receiver
        android:name=".BroadcastReceiver.NetworkStateReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
        tools:ignore="InnerclassSeparator">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"
                tools:ignore="BatteryLife" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

e estou tentando executar um código toda vez que o celular troca de conexão Wi-Fi, exemplo, ta conectado na REDE A, mas por algum motivo desconecta da REDE A e conecta na REDE B, essa ação eu quero interceptar e chamar o BroadcastReceiver, eu estou desenvolvendo um app que mantem um registro de todas as redes Wi-Fi em que o celular se conectou,

```
public class NetworkStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private ConnectionFirebase connectionFirebase;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =
            (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    onNetworkChange(networkInfo, context);
}

private void onNetworkChange(NetworkInfo networkInfo, Context context){
    if (connectionFirebase == null){
        connectionFirebase = new ConnectionFirebase();
    }
    if (networkInfo != null){
        if (networkInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED
                || networkInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING){
            connectionFirebase.saveNameWifi(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
    }
}
```

}

esse e meu BroadcastReceiver, ainda estou na faculdade e tentando aprender a usar o BroadcastReceiver, o meu problema é que o app não vê quando o celular muda a conexão com o Wi-Fi.

Comment: Verifique se isto está certo: `android:name=".BroadcastReceiver.NetworkStateReceiver"` e remova `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />`

Comment: .BroadcastReceiver é o nome do meu Package e .NetworkStateReceiver e o nome da minha classe que herda de BroadcastReceiver, esta certo.

Comment: eu removi <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> e ainda nao funciona

Comment: Eu preciso que isso funcione mesmo quando o aplicativo não estiver aberto

Comment: A solução do outro tópico deu certo, mas só funciona se o app estiver aberto, eu preciso que ele já esteja funcionando antes do usuário abrir o aplicativo.